# Stopping map.on() listener in Mapbox GL-JS

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am having difficulty understanding how to stop an event listener for my map after I set it. There are two other similar questions here but after effort I cannot get this to work for me.

My code to set the event listener is simple :

```
 map.on("move", function() {
    console.log("foo");
    }
  })
```

How can I stop this at will? I have tried `map.off('move');` but this does not work for me. I have also looked at the documentation at   [the mapbox docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/events/#evented#off)  but no luck there either.

The documentation shows that I need both :

1. Type (string) The event type to remove listeners for.
2. Listener (Function) The listener function to remove.

But, I don't know what I should be using as *listener*. (This is why I could only try `map.off('move');`).

How do I set .off() properly in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
const myfunc = () => console.log('foo');

map.on('move', myfunc);

map.off('move', myfunc);
```

You need to use either a static function or assign the arrow function to a variable in order to by able to call `off` with the exact same function.